# Need to display certain values stored in the AspNetUser table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using the code below to see if I can display the values of Description, Quantity, Price and Value stored in the AspNetUser table as can be seen. My first attempt in the 2nd 'IF' does not yield that
apart from the userid.
I went ahead to add the last three lines but the 'string' in the last line does not get accepted.

Someone please chip in an idea!!

```
 public partial class Account : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Description { get; internal set; }
    public string Quantity { get; internal set; }
    public string Price { get; internal set; }
    public string Value { get; internal set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                StatusText.Text = string.Format("Hello {0}!! ", User.Identity.GetUserName(), Description, Quantity, Price, Value);
                LoginStatus.Visible = true;
                LogoutButton.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                LoginForm.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = userManager.string(Description, Quantity, Price, Value);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I removed the last three statements above and added two other lines in their place so i now have below:

public partial class Account : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string Description { get; internal set; }
public string Quantity { get; internal set; }
public string Price { get; internal set; }
public string Value { get; internal set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
     StatusText.Text = string.Format("Hello {0}!! ", User.Identity.GetUserName(), Description, Quantity, Price, Value);                                         
     LoginStatus.Visible = true;
     LogoutButton.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            LoginForm.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    var user = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>  ().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    Response.Write(user.Description + "" + user.Quantity + "" + user.Price + "" + user.Value);

}
```

}

```
I have not run it yet but all the parameters were accepted in development.
```

Comment: I have since built the project and the page displays the desired values of Description, Quantity, Price and Value.